# Bash script and rows

Tags: mysql, arrays, bash

my problem is with rows mysql_query.
I need:

```
Record 0: 2,text is text,3.23
```

But I have:

```
Record 0: 2
Record 1: text
Record 2: is
Record 3: text
Record 4: 3.23
```

Please help me.

```
results=($(mysql --user root -proot test -Bse "select id,name from Object"));

cnt=${#results[@]}

for (( i=0 ; i<${cnt} ; i++ ))
do
    echo "Record No. $i: ${results[$i]}"

    fieldA=${results[0]};
    fieldB=${results[1]};

done
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're assigning `fieldA` and `fieldB` inside the `for` loop; if you want those to contain certain parts of each record, you shouldn't assign whole records to them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing the output of `mysql` into an array. Now, if `mysql` returns multiple records you won't know when a record ends and the next one starts because the array will contain the "flattened" data e.g. `( record1_fieldA record1_fieldB record2_fieldA record2_fieldB ... )`

Instead, use a `while` loop to iterate over the records like this:

```
i=0
while read fieldA fieldB
do
    echo "Record $(( i++ )): fieldA: $fieldA fieldB: $fieldB"
done < <(mysql --user root -proot test -Bse "select id,name from Object")
```

Comment: but, what when any field is empty? I have:
('aaao-230-27910', 1, 101, '0', '18435', ,);

I want:
('','aaao-230-27910', 1, 101, '0', '18435');

Comment: I use it:

while read fieldA fieldB fieldC fieldD fieldE fieldF fieldG fieldH fieldI fieldJ$ ...
do
    echo "$INS1 $fieldA, '$fieldB', '$fieldC', $fieldD, $fieldE, $fieldF, $field$ ...
done < <(mysql --user root -pnorbert test -Bse "select id, name, description, ....

Comment: And I have problem in Last field.
I have two field in one (0 and 23654):
...1, 101, 0 23654);